# Checkbox onChange event is not handled by handleChange props by Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I was building simple Form using `React` and `Formik` library.
I have added check box inside the `form` tag which is wrapped by `withFormik` wrapper of `formik` library.

I have tried to changing from

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name="flag"
  checked={values.flag}
  onChange={handleChange}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
/>
```

to

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name="flag"
  value={values.flag}
  onChange={handleChange}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
/>
```

but none is working.

the component is as following

```
import { withFormik } from 'formik';
...

const Form = props => (
  <form>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="flag"
      checked={props.values.flag}
      onChange={props.handleChange}
      onBlur={props.handleBlur}
    />
    <input
      type="text"
      name="name"
      checked={props.values.name}
      onChange={props.handleChange}
      onBlur={props.handleBlur}
    />
  </form>
);

const WrappedForm = withFormik({
  displayName: 'BasicForm',
})(Form);

export default WrappedForm;
```

It should change props.values when clicking checkbox.
but it doesn't change props data at all.

Btw, it changes props data when typing in text input box.
This only happens with `checkbox`.

Comment: FYI: it works well with other tags like text input box.

Comment: Seems to work fine? working version: https://codesandbox.io/embed/dark-mountain-vy3qj

Comment: i was using the customized checkbox component instead of primitive `input` element.
and the issue was on there.
@jagsler thanks for your time.

Comment: @JonathanBogdanovicz can you post example of where the issue is, since you said primitive is not what you are using instead you have custom, in that case post custom code, may be the issue is over there

Comment: @LangReactDev Were you able to resolve the issue. If yes can you please share your solution? I am facing same issue for the custom checkbox.

Answer (score 18):

Using the setFieldValue from Formik props, you can set the value of the check to true or false.

```
<CheckBox
checked={values.check}
onPress={() => setFieldValue('check', !values.check)}
/>
```

My answer relates to react-native checkbox.

This article is very helpful. https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/handling-different-field-types-in-react-native-forms-with-formik-and-yup-fa9ea89d867e

Answer (score 11):

Im using react material ui library, here is how i manage my checkboxes :

```
import { FormControlLabel, Checkbox} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";

         <Formik
            initialValues={{
              check: false
            }}
           onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
              setSubmitting(false);
            }, 400);
          }}
        >
          {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
            <Form className="gt-form">
              <FormControlLabel
                checked={values.check}
                onChange={() => setFieldValue("check", !values.check)}
                control={<Checkbox />}
                label="save this for later"
              />
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
```